# How can I make a multicall transaction using web3.py and pancakeswap router?

Tags: blockchain, web3.py, pancakeswap

I need to do a multihop swap. For example : BNB->USDT->TOKEN. I am trying to do this swap using pancakeswap roter v2 swapExactETHForTokens method. But I get execution reverted

```
swap_path = [input_token_address,
                Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955'),
                output_token_address]
tx = self.contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(min_tokens, swap_path, account_address (int(time.time()) + 10000)).buildTransaction(
    
    { 'from': account_address,
      'value': input_quantity_wei,
      'gasPrice': Web3.toWei(current_gas, 'gwei'),
      'nonce': self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address)
    })
```

How can I perform such a swap in a single transaction using web3 py?